What is exact meaning for "as" in "as in duty bound"?
Everyone, my question is on the post title. I am sure the "as" is a conj., but I am expecting the exact meaning it conveys. Can somebody help?

I will as in duty bound, honestly and faithfully defend his Majesty, his heirs and successors in person, crown and dignity, against all enemies.


...specifically, the exact cited text first appeared in The Statutes of the United Kingdom of Great Britain, 1829.

Marriam-webster adv.

3 : when considered in a specified form or relation —usually used
before a preposition or a participle

Though other definitions could also be understood. The conjunction listing is not far off.

3 : in the way or manner that Do as I do.

…as I am in duty bound…
It’s unlikely that this exact string will appear in a dictionary, but the idea is clear enough looking at these definitions.
